# Is there a slang word or phrase for a middle-aged woman who serially dates much younger men?

Tags: phrases, slang

Such practice is observed more often in the artistic world and among socialites. Is there a slang word or frase for these ladies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cougar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cougar) (slang):

> an older woman seeking a sexual relationship with a younger man.

Per the Huffington Post:

> And while celebrities like Demi Moore, Madonna, Jennifer Lopez and Sharon Stone may have helped officially introduce the word ["cougar"](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/05/30/celebrity-cougars-female-stars-younger-men_n_3361677.html) into the English Oxford Dictionary (formally defined as "older women seeking a sexual relationship with younger men"), they aren't the only women in Hollywood who've gone much younger when picking their partners.

Comment: Never seen someone so quick.

Comment: @Centaurus - I'm fairly surprised that you didn't know this.

Comment: There is also [_puma_](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=puma_). They are the younger version of cougars (around 30s) seeking/dating younger guys.

Comment: And of course Mountain Lion, for much older women dating much younger men.

Comment: @Minnow: Let's not explain the _African lions_. Shall we not?

Comment: And [_smilodon_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smilodon), for reeeeeally old women dating much younger men (which in this case would be any male who hasn't actually begun fossilizing).